# Isolating frequencies and phases of superposed cosine functions

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

This problem is mathematical, but it is needed in physics. I have points on the graph of the function $y = f(x)$. These points were obtained experimentally. I have a lot of such graphs. The pictures below show only two examples. It is known that $f(x) = A_{1}\cos(w_{1}x + \phi_{1}) + A_{2}\cos(w_{2}x + \phi_{2})$, where $A_{1}, w_{1}, A_{2}, w_{2}, \phi_{1}, \phi_{2}$ are some constants (real parameters) and $w_{1} > 0, w_{2} > 0$. I need to determine the approximate values of numbers $A_{1}, w_{1}, A_{2}, w_{2}$ knowing what the graph of a function looks like. I want to know the values of numbers $A_{1}, w_{1}, A_{2}, w_{2}$ even with a large error, for example, with an error of 50%. I need to know this so that I can use a computer program OriginLab to analyze this graph.

**My question.** The graph of the function clearly shows where the extremum points are. You can see the values of the function at the extremum points. The points of intersection of the graph of the function with the abscissa axis are also clearly visible. Is it possible on the basis of this to find approximate (not exact) values of numbers $A_{1}, w_{1}, A_{2}, w_{2}$ ? I would like to know not only the method of how to do this, but I also want to know the mathematical proof of this method. It is about a method how to calculate these parameters on paper. This is not about numerical methods.

**My work.** At the moment, I do not know this method. On the Internet, you can find special cases of how this function looks, but I'm interested in the general case for arbitrary values of $A_{1}, w_{1}, A_{2}, w_{2}, \phi_{1}, \phi_{2}$. I tried to investigate the function myself using differentiation, but very complex transcendental equations are obtained.
[image]

Comment: I believe you should get something like the larger frequency being a constant factor (iirc some power of $2$) times $\omega_1+\omega_2$ and the smaller frequency being a constant factor times $\omega_1-\omega_2$. Similarly, the larger amplitude will be $A_1+A_2$ and the smaller amplitude will be $|A_1-A_2|$. If you're interested in the phase shifts, you can substitute some points and solve for them.

Comment: Indeed this is highly useful in a large number of fields, and has therefore been the subject of much research. For example, check out this recent [Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgF3OX8nT0w). What you are looking for is called the "Inverse Fourier Transform", though you only want the discrete version of it. You should also look for "Fast Fourier Transform" to see how it can be calculated efficiently.

Comment: You really want the Discrete/Fast Fourier Transform for this.  All of the parameters you seek are estimated by the transform.  You  have to be careful with scaling and window function gains when estimating amplitudes.  You can use cross spectrum correlation  to refine the frequency estimates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, discrete Fourier series do not really help here since these functions are not even periodic in general.  Instead, the parameters can be recovered by using a linear recurrence. If you sample such a function on a fixed frequency then every five subsequent values satisfy a fixed linear relation.  So take $$f(k) = A \cos(\omega_1 k + \varphi_1) + B \cos(\omega_2 k + \varphi_2)$$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$.  Assume the generic case where $\cos(\omega_1) \neq \cos(\omega_2)$ and both unequal to $\pm 1$. Then there exist unique $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $$f(k) + c_1 f(k+1) + c_2 f(k+2) + c_1 f(k+3) + f(k+4) = 0$$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$. In particular these coefficients can be derived from any six subsequent values of $f$ by solving two linear equations in $c_1, c_2$. The characteristic polynomial for this recurrence factors as $$1 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + c_1 x^3 + x^4 = (x^2 - 2 \cos(\omega_1) x + 1)(x^2 - 2 \cos(\omega_2) x + 1).$$  This recovers $\cos(\omega_1)$ and $\cos(\omega_2)$ as solutions of the quadratic equation $$4x^2 + 2 c_1 x + c_2-2 = 0.$$  Now $f$ can be fitted as a linear combination of the four functions $$\cos(\omega_1 k), \sin(\omega_1 k), \cos(\omega_2 k), \sin(\omega_2 k)$$ noting that $$\cos(\omega k + \varphi) = \cos(\varphi) \cos(\omega k) - \sin(\varphi) \sin(\omega k).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard question and I believe there are many solution approaches. I like the Bayesian techniques described in the book "Bayesian Spectrum Analysis and Parameter Estimation" by Larry Bretthorst (who was a PhD student of E T Jaynes) because they deal with noise quite gracefully. The basic setting is the following: the observed data is $(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$ for which we use the model:
$$y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$$ where $$f(x) = A_1 \cos(\omega_1 x + \Phi_1) + A_2 \cos(\omega_2 x + \Phi_2)$$ and $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$ are errors commonly modeled as independently distributed according to a zero-mean normal distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$. One can assume that $x_1, \dots, x_n$ (which need not be equally spaced) are deterministic (or one can do the analysis conditional on the observed $x_1, \dots, x_n$). The goal is to recover the unknown parameters $\omega_1, \omega_2, A_1, A_2, \Phi_1, \Phi_2$ (note the noise level $\sigma$ is also an unknown parameter) from data $(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$. It is convenient to reparametrize the function $f$ as $$f(x) = a_1 \cos(\omega_1 x) + b_1 \sin(\omega_1 x) + a_2 \cos(\omega_2 x) + b_2 \sin (\omega_2 x)$$ where $a_i = A_i \cos(\Phi_i)$ and $b_i = -A_i \sin(\Phi_i)$. The model can be rewritten as: $$Y = X(\omega_1, \omega_2) \beta + \epsilon$$ where $Y$ is the vector with components $y_1, \dots, y_n$, $X$ is the $n \times 4$ matrix with columns corresponding to the evaluations of the four functions $\cos(\omega_1 x)$, $\sin(\omega_1 x)$, $\cos(\omega_2 x)$ and $\sin(\omega_2 x)$ for $x = x_1, \dots, x_n$, $\beta$ is the $4 \times 1$ vector with components $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$ and $\epsilon$ is the $n \times 1$ noise vector with components $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$. If $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are known, this is a simple linear model which leads to easy estimation of $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$ by least squares. When $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are unknown, this is a nonlinear model.

Now to estimate the unknown parameters, in a Bayesian approach, we need to make prior probabilistic assumptions on the unknown parameters $\omega_i, a_i, b_i$ (for $i=1,2$) and $\sigma$. A simple assumption reflecting prior ignorance on the values of these parameters is: $$\omega_1, a_1, b_1, \omega_2, a_2, b_2, \log \sigma \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} \text{Unif}(-C, C)$$ where $C$ is a very large positive constant (here Unif refers to the uniform distribution). The exact value of $C$ should not have a major effect on the results below (as long as $C$ is large).

The modeling assumptions allow us to calculate the conditional distribution of the parameters $$\theta = (\omega_1, \omega_2, a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \sigma) = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \beta, \sigma)$$ given the observed data (this is called the posterior distribution) by the use of Bayes rule: $$\begin{aligned}& p(\theta \mid \text{data}) \propto p(\theta) p(\text{data}\mid \theta) \\ & = \frac{(2C)^{-7}}{\sigma} I\{-C < \omega_1,\omega_2, a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \log \sigma < C\} \\ &\quad\, \times \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \right)^n  \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \|Y - X(\omega_1, \omega_2) \beta\|^2 \right) \\ &\propto I\{-C < \omega_1,\omega_2, a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \log \sigma < C\} \sigma^{-n-1} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \|Y - X(\omega_1, \omega_2) \beta\|^2 \right) \end{aligned}.$$ This posterior density (suitably normalized so it integrates to one) captures uncertainty in the parameters $\theta$ after observing the data. The indicator term is generally irrelevant as the term $$\sigma^{-n-1} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \|Y - X(\omega_1, \omega_2) \beta\|^2 \right)$$ will usually be negligibly small outside the set $-C < \omega_1,\omega_2, a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \log \sigma < C$. Let us drop the indicator to get the simpler expression $$p(\theta \mid \text{data}) \propto \sigma^{-n-1} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \|Y - X(\omega_1, \omega_2) \beta\|^2 \right).$$

If we are not interested in certain parameters, we can just integrate those away. Suppose we are only interested in the frequency parameters $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, we can then integrate away $\beta$ and $\sigma$. To integrate over $\beta$, we can write (with $X = X(\omega_1, \omega_2)$: $$\|Y - X \beta\|^2 = \|Y - X \hat{\beta}\|^2 + \|X \hat{\beta} - X \beta\|^2 = \|Y - X \hat{\beta}\|^2 + (\beta - \hat{\beta})^T X^T X (\beta - \hat{\beta})$$ where $\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$ is the least squares estimate of $Y$ on $X$, and also
note $$\int \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (\beta - \hat{\beta})^T X^T X (\beta - \hat{\beta}) \right) d\beta = (\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi})^p |X^T X|^{-1/2}$$ where $p = 4$ (assuming that $X$ has full column rank; otherwise, one can drop some columns in $X$) and $|\cdot|$ denotes determinant. This gives
$$p(\omega_1, \omega_2, \sigma \mid \text{data}) \propto \sigma^{-n+p-1} \exp \left(-\frac{\|Y - X \hat{\beta}\|^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) |X^TX|^{-1/2}.$$ Note that the dependence on $\omega_1, \omega_2$ in the right hand side is through the matrix $X = X(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ and the vector $\hat{\beta}$. $\sigma$ can be easily integrated away from the above to obtain $$p(\omega_1, \omega_2 \mid \text{data}) \propto \|Y - X \hat{\beta}\|^{-n+p} |X^T X|^{-1/2}.$$ This density allows estimation of $\omega_1, \omega_2$ as well as uncertainty quantification. Practically this can be implemented as follows:

1. Take a grid of values for $\omega_1, \omega_2$. For each value of $\omega_1, \omega_2$ in the grid, form the matrix $X = X(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ and perform least squares of $Y$ on $X$ to calculate $\hat{\beta}$. Then calculate the value of $h(\omega_1, \omega_2) := \|Y - X \hat{\beta}\|^{-n+p} |X^T X|^{-1/2}$. Do this for each pair of values $\omega_1,\omega_2$ in the grid and then normalize $h(\cdot, \cdot)$ so it sums to one over all $\omega_1,\omega_2$ in the grid.
2. Plot the function $h(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ for $\omega_1,\omega_2$ in the grid. Typically, it will have a single sharp maximum at some $\hat{\omega}_1, \hat{\omega}_2$. You can then take $\hat{\omega}_1, \hat{\omega}_2$ to be accurate point estimates of $\omega_1, \omega_2$.
3. After obtaining $\hat{\omega}_1, \hat{\omega}_2$, do least squares of $Y$ on $\hat{X} := X(\hat{\omega}_1, \hat{\omega}_2)$ to obtain estimates of $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$.

This method generalizes in a straightforward manner to deal with a larger number of sinusoids $\sum_j A_j \cos(\omega_j x + \Phi_j)$ (although the grid search method for estimating $\omega_1, \dots, \omega_k$ will be computationally intensive for larger $k$). The book ("Bayesian spectrum analysis and parameter estimation" by Bretthorst) also deals with the case of unknown $k$.

Comment: As I understand it, you suggested a numerical method. I asked about a method how to calculate these parameters on paper.

Comment: @Witold from numerical input data, one must use numerical methods to estimate parameters and iterate to refine estimates.  You aren't providing analytic input.  The input is samples (numbers) of finite precision, so the output is necessarily going to be estimates.  Why would you expect some analytic solution to exist?

Comment: I hope there is an analytical solution. The function is not very complicated, there are not many parameters. Therefore, intuition suggests that there must be an analytical solution.